# How to sort by a field of the pivot table of a many-to-many relationship in Eloquent ORM

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have been using Eloquent ORM for some time now and I know it quite well, but I can't do the following, while **it's very easy to do in Fluent**.

I have users with a many-to-many songs, intermediate table being song_user (like it should be). I'd like to get the top songs of a user, judging by the play count. Of course, play count is stored in the intermediate table.

I can do it in Fluent:

```
$songs = DB::table('songs')
    ->join('song_user', 'songs.id', '=', 'song_user.song_id')
    ->where('song_user.user_id', '=', $user->id)
    ->orderBy("song_user.play_count", "desc")
    ->get();
```

Easy. But I want to do it in Eloquent, which of course **doesn't work:**

```
$songs = Song::
    with(array("song_user" => function($query) use ($user) {
        $query->where("user_id", "=", $user->id)->orderBy("play_count", "desc");
    }))
```

Comment: I have no setup to try it out, but have you tried something like `$songs = $usr->songs()->pivot()->order_by('play_count','desc')->songs();`? Question is if you can "get back" to `songs` after the pivot table, since it does not seem to be a normal model.

Comment: This doesn't work, unfortunatelly.

Comment: Well you can always make the pivot table a *model* and work through that. You'd only have to set up additional foreign keys so that the entries are correctly removed when their respective parent is.

Comment: I am currently doing that, but using this approach, you lose the automatic filtering of user-only songs ($user->songs()) and you have to remember to manually do it (`SongUser::where("user_id", "=", $user->id)->etc...`).

Comment: Why, this is what relations are for, instead of one many-to-many you make two one-to-many relations with the pivot table. You'd just add something like `$this->has_many('song_user')`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Not sure if you plan to move to Laravel 4, but here's an Eloquent example for sorting by a pivot tables fields:

```
public function songs() {
  return $this
    ->belongsToMany('Song')
    ->withPivot('play_count')
    ->orderBy('pivot_play_count', 'desc');
}
```

`withPivot` is like the eloquent `with` and will add the `play_count` field from the pivot table to the other keys it already includes. All the pivot table fields are prefixed with `pivot` in the results, so you can reference them directly in the `orderBy`.

I've no idea what it would look like in Laravel 3, but perhaps this will help point you in the right direction.

Cheers!

Comment: I didn't know I could stick the orderBy in the model like that. You deserve at least +1 for that!

Comment: Would you please point out if pivot fields prefixing mentioned in the documentation?

Comment: Works in Laravel 5.2 without needing to prefix the pivot table fields

Answer (score 5):

I just found something in the user guide, apparently you need the [`with()`](http://laravel.com/api/class-Laravel.Database.Eloquent.Relationships.Has_Many_And_Belongs_To.html#_with) method.

From the [User-Guide](http://laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent#many-to-many):

> By default only certain fields from the pivot table will be returned
>   (the two id fields, and the timestamps). If your pivot table contains
>   additional columns, you can fetch them too by using the with() method
>   :
>
> ```php
> class User extends Eloquent {
>   public function roles()
>   {
>     return $this->has_many_and_belongs_to('Role', 'user_roles')->with('column');
>   }
> }
> ```

So you can then use something similar to this when defining your relationship:

```php
$this->has_many_and_belongs_to('User')->with('playcount');
```

### Example

I just used this to make sure it works...

```php
class Song extends Eloquent {
    function users()
    {
        return $this->has_many_and_belongs_to('User')->with('playcount');
    }
}

class User extends Eloquent {
    function songs()
    {
        return $this->has_many_and_belongs_to('Song')->with('playcount');
    }
}

// My test method
class TestOrm extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function testSomethingIsTrue()
    {
        foreach(User::find(3)->songs()->order_by('playcount')->get() as $song)
            echo $song->name, ': ', $song->pivot->playcount, "\n";
        echo "\n";
        foreach(User::find(3)->songs()->order_by('playcount','desc')->get() as $song)
            echo $song->name, ': ', $song->pivot->playcount, "\n";
    }
}
```

### Output

```
Jingle Bells: 5
Mary had a little lamb: 10
Soft Kitty: 20
The Catalyst: 100

The Catalyst: 100
Soft Kitty: 20
Mary had a little lamb: 10
Jingle Bells: 5
```

**Note**: It is no coincidence that without using `order_by()` the result appears sorted in `ascending` order by the `playcount`. I confirmed this through testing (as I do not know yet how to display queries in unit tests), but you should probably not rely on this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Any method that's available in Fluent should also be available with Eloquent.  Perhaps this is what you're looking for?

```
$songs = Song->join('song_user', 'songs.id', '=', 'song_user.song_id')
->where('song_user.user_id', '=', $user->id)
->orderBy("song_user.play_count", "desc")
->get();
```

Comment: No, I'm looking for a more eloquent way of doing it, see my example that doesn't work.

Comment: The answer I posted does user Eloquent.  It will return an array of Eloquent objects (songs in this case) belonging to a user and ordered via play_count field (from the join table).  This could also be done directly form the user object whose songs you're trying to find $user->songs()->order_by('play_count', 'asc')->get().  Your failed example doesn't make any sense:  eager loading the song_user pivot table isn't the same as creating a join and in this case, there's really no reason for you to be eager loading.  A simple join should accomplish what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing this ( on several builds ) simply using the relationship method as you have. I often use an 'order' column in the pivot table and then do something like this.

```
$article->tags()->order_by( 'order')->get();
```

This may be ambiguous if you have columns named 'order' in the joining table. If so you would need to specify ->order_by( 'article_tag.order' ). And yes, you need to use ->with() to get that column in the result set. As just a matter of style I would leave the with() out of the relationship method and just return the vanilla relationship object instead.

Answer (score 0):

In your Eloquent model you can chain the orderBy column if you include the table name:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post')->withTimestamps()->orderByDesc('posts.created_at');
```