# Laravel 4 Eloquent: Many-to-many with conditions on joining table

Tags: many-to-many, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am attempting to rewrite some logic for a database which was previously used with Codeigniter. The design is such that some of the conditions for a many-to-many join are stored in the joining table like so:

```
Table user
  - user_id
  ...

Table avatars
  - user_id
  - image_id
  - uploaded_timestamp
  - deleted_timestamp

Table images
  - image_id
  ...
```

In this case, I want to get all images associated with a user through the avatars table, ordered by time uploaded time descending, and not including deleted avatars (deleted_timestamp not null).

I have discovered that using Eloquent's hasMany does not allow conditions on the joining table. What is the cleanest way to achieve this affect, or do i need to resort to building a full query in the way I used to with Codeigniter's active record class?

**Note:** I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14346014/2047696) which suggests using `->hasMany(..)->with('another_column_from_pivot_table')`, but that only seems to work with Laravel 3's Eloquent implementation. It seems ->with is now for eagar loading only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*hasMany()* is intended for one-to-many relations.  Many-to-many expects *belongsToMany()* -- that's the statement that ties to the itermediate ("pivot") table.

I haven't tried it, but I can believe that belongsToMany() wouldn't work with a where() statement. I know that hasMany() does fine with a where().

What you may need to do is create a third model class:

(WARNING: untested code)

```
class User extends Eloquent {
   public avatars() {
      return $this->hasMany('Avatar')
                  ->where ('deleted_timestamp',0)
                  ->orderBy('uploaded_timestamp','desc');
   }
}

class Avatar extends Eloquent {
  public image() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Image');
  }
}

class Image extends Eloquent {
}
```

You'd access your images as...

```
$avatars = User::find($user_id)->avatars();
foreach ($avatars as $avatar) {
   echo '<img src="$avatar->image->url">';
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've also discovered that you can use `->withPivot('column_name')` in order to get the pivot table's column values returned with the collection from belongsToMany. But as you point out, this still leaves me with no way to add order and where to filter the collection. You're approach will work, along with using a foreach on the collection and manually extracting and ordering, but yours is more ideal. Thanks!